# How can I post code within spoiler markdown?

Tags: support, markdown

In a recent answer [on a recent question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/96379/31562) there was code written within a spoiler. I edited the post a bit to format the markdown better, but I ended up with something that just looks... horrible...

How can code be written within a spoiler in posts?

What I ended up with was:

```
>! `somefunction`<br>
>!  &nbsp;&nbsp;`indented line`<br>
>!  &nbsp;&nbsp;`another indented line`<br>
>!  &nbsp;&nbsp;`return something`<br>
>! `end`
```

This shows as:

> `somefunction`
>     `indented line`
>     `another indented line`
>     `return something`
>  `end`

but I find that the markdown to accomplish that is really ugly.

Comment: spoiler markdown is one of these beasts...

Comment: Suddenly I get the feeling this might end up as a bug, or feature-request, or a duplicate of some post on MSE...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166004/148099

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217779/148099

Comment: Why are we posting code inside spoilers?

Comment: @nhgrif code-review teaches to fish, it does not give fish, giving a fish inside spoiler tags may help future visitors though.

Comment: You can teach to fish without giving the fish and without using the spoiler.  I find spoiler sections highly unnecessary and inappropriate on Code Review.  Likely, I'd downvote most posts I see with spoiler sections.

Comment: @nhgrif Whether or not to use code inside spoilers is a bit of a different question. This question is focusing on *how* to do it for those who might want to do it.

Comment: That's why I haven't posted an answer...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Welp. This is the best solution I came up with. If you're okay with using `<pre>`, then this is probably the best.

```
>! <pre>
>! if(solution.SolutionBad == "possibly") {
>!     print "Code in spoilers!";
>! }
>! </pre>
```

Output:

> ```
>  if(solution.SolutionBad == "possibly") {
>      print "Code in spoilers!";
>  }
> ```

---

If you put the closing `</pre>` on the last line of code, that will remove one extra blank line at the end.

```
>! <pre>
>! if(solution.SolutionBad == "possibly") {
>!     print "Code in spoilers!";
>! } </pre>
```

Output:

> ```
>  if(solution.SolutionBad == "possibly") {
>      print "Code in spoilers!";
>  }
> ```